# resizing image for a bar

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, image

I am resizing a image to fit it in a bar. I need to resize it because the image is in a db and this is use for the same app in android too. the thing is this code is working well in `iOS 6.1` but in lower `5.0 5.1` I am having a black image in the bar. The code is the following:

```
CGSize newSize=CGSizeMake(320,44);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:newImage  forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

some ideas of this wrong behavior?

[image: good]

[image: bad]

Thanks

Comment: - (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)backgroundImage forBarMetrics:(UIBarMetrics)barMetrics only support 5.0+

Comment: yes but I have this problem in 5.0 and 5.1 but not in 6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following method for specific **hight** and **width** with **image**

```
+ (UIImage*)resizeImage:(UIImage*)image withWidth:(int)width withHeight:(int)height
{
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
    float widthRatio = newSize.width/image.size.width;
    float heightRatio = newSize.height/image.size.height;

    if(widthRatio > heightRatio)
    {
        newSize=CGSizeMake(image.size.width*heightRatio,image.size.height*heightRatio);
    }
    else
    {
        newSize=CGSizeMake(image.size.width*widthRatio,image.size.height*widthRatio);
    }


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

This method return **NewImage**, with specific size that you specify :)
This code may be helpful for you:)